# Starting docker-compose with systemd on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: docker, systemd, ubuntu-15.04

I have a docker-compose project that I would like to control through systemd. In upstart, I would use a script that looks like this:

```
description "Start/Stop server"
author "Jim Cortez"

start on filesystem and started docker
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn limit 3 240

pre-start script
    # wait (if necessary) for our docker context to be accessible
    while [ ! -f /projects/my_server/docker-compose.yml ]
    do
      sleep 1
    done
    /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /projects/my_server/docker-compose.yml up -d
end script

script
    sleepWhileAppIsUp(){
        while docker ps | grep "$1" >/dev/null; do
            sleep 2
        done
    }

    sleepWhileAppIsUp "my_server"
end script

# stop docker container after the stop event has completed
post-stop script
    if docker ps | grep my_server;
    then
        /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /projects/my_server/docker-compose.yml stop
    fi
end script
```

(above adapted from [here](http://blog.ianholden.com/using-docker-with-upstart/))

However, I am now running on a docker host that runs Ubuntu 15.04, which has switched to systemd. How can I do the above as a systemd service script? Simply launching the docker-compose daemon will not allow systemd to track and restart in case of failure.

Here is what I have so far:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Server container
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /projects/my_server/docker-compose.yml up -d
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /projects/my_server/docker-compose.yml stop

[Install]
WantedBy=local.target
```

Answer (score 11):

I suggest removing the `-d` option. You do not need to run the containers in the background in this case.

Comment: When removing `-d` and executing a start of the unit, it will block the prompt until the container is finished, which, depending on the workload, may be never.

Answer (score 6):

I found that: The author uses a similar approach as you http://trackless.ca/2015/12/21/docker-compose-meets-systemd/. But additionally he creates one systemd service for each docker-compose service.

You might consider to convert your docker-compose file to multiple systemd service files to get rid of the docker-compose dependency: http://container-transform.readthedocs.org/
I used that approach, it works fine for simple setups.

Comment: you might want to put some additional information from the links in your answer, links tend to do not work after some time.

Comment: indeed, the link don't work anymore ^^.

Comment: Here's an Internet Archive link to the first blog post: http://web.archive.org/web/20161105135126/http://trackless.ca/2015/12/21/docker-compose-meets-systemd/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I found in my test, it require more time than normal service to start or stop.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Server container
Requires=docker.service
After=network.target docker.service

[Service]
#Restart=always
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/projects/my_server
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /projects/my_server/docker-compose.yml up
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /projects/my_server/docker-compose.yml down

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: i think you should use WorkingDirectory. docker-compose use current working directory to load .env files

WorkingDirectory=/projects/my_server

also ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose up